# Displaying Multiple JSON Responds onto HTML as Single Value

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I subscribed to a weather API that returns data in JSON. That data comes back with multiple values :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "error": null,
  "response": [
    {
      "periods": [
        { "snowIN": 0.15 },
        { "snowIN": 0.15 },
        { "snowIN": 0.18 },
        { "snowIN": 0.18 },
        { "snowIN": 0.18 },
        { "snowIN": 0.18 },
        { "snowIN": 0.18 },
        { "snowIN": 0.18 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.24 },
        { "snowIN": 0.03 },
        { "snowIN": 0.03 },
        { "snowIN": 0.03 },
        { "snowIN": 0.03 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to take these values, get the total sum and display it in my HTML.

How do I do that?

> Get a total amount of snowfall `snowIN` during a 48 hour period and display the value as a text on html.

I have tried this coding...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.aerisapi.com/sdk/js/latest/aerisweather.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    window.onload = () => {

        const target = document.getElementById('data-reading');
        const aeris = new AerisWeather('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET');

        const request = aeris.api().endpoint('forecasts').place('pierre,sd').filter('1hr').limit('48');
        request.get().then((result) => {
            const data = result.data;
            const { periods } = data[0];
            if (periods) {
                periods.reverse().forEach(period => {
                    const snowIN = period.snowIN || '0.00';

                    const html = (`
                                 <p class="map-datavalue">${snowIN}"</p>
                            `);

                    target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
                });
            }
        }); 
    }

</script>
```

The results show all the `snowIN` values, not as one.  I have also put my `const aeris = new AerisWeather('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET')` when I ran the html.

Comment: Do a little searching; there are literally hundreds of questions about summing values from an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
// Once you have the results
const api_result = {"success":true,"error":null,"response":[{"periods":[{"snowIN":0.15},{"snowIN":0.15},{"snowIN":0.18},{"snowIN":0.18},{"snowIN":0.18},{"snowIN":0.18},{"snowIN":0.18},{"snowIN":0.18},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.24},{"snowIN":0.03},{"snowIN":0.03},{"snowIN":0.03},{"snowIN":0.03}]}]};
let sum;
try {
  // Use reduce to calculate the sum
  sum = api_result.response[0].periods.reduce((r, v) => r+v.snowIN, 0);
  // JS math is not exact, so we use `toFixed` to only keep 2 decimals
  sum = sum.toFixed(2);
} catch(e) {
  // In case the data is not complete
  sum = "not available";
}
document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<h1>The sum is <span id="sum"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to data like this way.

```
const data = {"succes": true, ...}
data.response.map((value, key) => {
    // value is mapping to peridos. 
})
```

Function map() may not be a absolutely correct way to get sum of data, but can be. (Look [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))
I recommend you to practice first with easy data.